# Form state in a modal is systematically overriden by initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a video project manager, considering a video project at a given route /projects/:id. I want to edit data from this existing project (name, description, type) which is retrieved from a mock JSON file (later, it will be fetched from an API). When I click on "Edit project", a modal with an embedded form opens and the existing form data is properly retrieved. When I want to edit the form by typing text or clicking on a radio button option, the form data is updated, but the  component is re-rendered immediately after and the form data is reset to its initial value, so nothing visually happens.

I've spent hours with ChatGPT which gave me many hook suggestions that don't solve the problem (useEffect, useRef, useMemo, useCallback), so I guess there is something wrong with the data structure or management here.

Here is the current Project.jsx code :

```
import mock from "../services/mock.json";
import {Card} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useLoaderData} from "react-router-dom";
import {useState, useRef} from "react";
import ConfirmationModal from "../components/ConfirmationModal/ConfirmationModal";
import EditVideoProjectForm from "../components/EditVideoProjectForm/EditVideoProjectForm";

export async function loader({params}) {
  const project = await mock.list.find(item => item.id === Number(params.projectId));
  return {project};
}

export default function Project() {
  const loaderData = useLoaderData();
  const {project} = loaderData;
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [modalOptions, setModalOptions] = useState(null);
  const editProject = () => {
    console.log("Project", project.name, "was edited");
  };
  const initialFormData = {
    name: project.name,
    description: project.description,
    type: project.type,
  };
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false); // Used for form validation
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value
    })
  };
  const openEditModal = () => {
    setModalOptions({
      title: "Edit project",
      content: <EditVideoProjectForm ref={formRef}
                                       formData={formData}
                                       validated={validated}
                                       handleInput={handleInput}
      />,
      callback: () => editProject(project)
    });
    setShowModal(true);
  };
  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setModalOptions(null);
    setShowModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ConfirmationModal show={showModal}
                         title={modalOptions?.title}
                         handleSubmit={modalOptions?.callback}
                         handleClose={handleCloseModal}
      >
        {modalOptions?.content}
      </ConfirmationModal>
      <a href={`/projects/`}>&lt; Back to projects</a>
      <Card className="Project" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{project.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{project.description}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card.Footer className="Project--footer">
          <div className="Project--link" onClick={openEditModal}>Edit project</div>
        </Card.Footer>
      </Card>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(formData)}</code>
    </>
  );
}
```

And the EditVideoProjectForm.jsx component:

```
import "./EditVideoProjectForm.css";
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {Form} from "react-bootstrap";

const EditVideoProjectForm = React.forwardRef(({formData, validated, handleInput}, ref) => {
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.current = {
        getFormValidity: () => formRef.current.checkValidity(),
      };
    }
  }, [ref]);
  return (
    <>
      <Form noValidate ref={formRef} validated={validated}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="nameEditVideoProject">
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control required
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        placeholder="Name of your project"
                        value={formData.name}
                        onChange={handleInput}
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            Please provide a project name.
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="descEditVideoProject">
          <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control required
                        as="textarea"
                        name="description"
                        placeholder="What your project is about"
                        value={formData.description}
                        onChange={handleInput}
          />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            Please provide a project description.
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label>Video editing type</Form.Label>
          <Form.Check type="radio"
                      label="Automated"
                      name="type"
                      id="auto"
                      value="auto"
                      checked={formData.type === 'auto'}
                      onChange={handleInput}
          />
          <Form.Check type="radio"
                      label="Manual (by an editor)"
                      name="type"
                      id="manual"
                      value="manual"
                      checked={formData.type === 'manual'}
                      onChange={handleInput}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
});

export default EditVideoProjectForm;
```

The ConfirmationModal.jsx component has a simple structure:

```
import "./ConfirmationModal.css";
import {Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function ConfirmationModal({children, show, title, handleSubmit, handleClose}) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(show);
  const handleCancel = () => {
    handleClose();
  }
  const handleConfirm = (event) => {
    handleSubmit(event);
    handleClose();
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowModal(show);
  }, [show]);
  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          {title ? <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title> : null}
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {children}
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCancel}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button type="submit" variant="primary" onClick={handleConfirm}>
            Confirm
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

And the mock JSON structure:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Project 1",
      "type": "auto",
      "author": "Chuck Norris",
      "description": "This is my first project, this is a test.",
      "isArchived": false,
      "creationDate": "2023-03-09T14:00:00.000Z",
      "modificationDate": "2023-03-09T15:11:42.000Z",
      "nbViews": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's a visual preview of the result:
[image]